# How to remove tag attribute from xml file using java

Tags: java, xml

I want to remove some attribute and some tags from my origin xml file using java, if somebody can help me i will be very happy. Thank you.

XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<html>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="Center" rules="cols" bordercolor="#999999" border="1" id="DataGrid1" bgcolor="White" height="8" width="624" style="Z-INDEX: 111; LEFT: 120px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 128px"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr bgcolor="#000084"> 
   <td><font color="White"><b>Date</b></font></td>
   <td><font color="White"><b>Time</b></font></td>
   <td><font color="White"><b>Quay</b></font></td>
   <td><font color="White"><b>Vessel</b></font></td>
   <td><font color="White"><b>Call Reference Number</b></font></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
   <td><font color="Black">01.01.2014</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">11:00</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">P7</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">&quot;SELFOSS&quot;</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">NLRTM13029124 </font></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="Gainsboro"> 
   <td><font color="Black">01.01.2014</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">15:00</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">P6</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">&quot;NEDLLOYD MARITA&quot;</font></td>
   <td><font color="Black">NLRTM13029408 </font></td> 
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <table>
  <html>
```

I want to change this xml to,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<html>
<table> 
 <tbody>
  <tr> 
   <td>Date</td>
   <td>Time</td>
   <td>Quay</td>
   <td>Vessel</td>
   <td>Call Reference Number</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>01.01.2014</td>
   <td>11:00</td>
   <td>P7</td>
   <td>&quot;SELFOSS&quot;</td>
   <td>NLRTM13029124</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>01.01.2014</font></td>
   <td>15:00</font></td>
   <td>P6</font></td>
   <td>&quot;NEDLLOYD MARITA&quot;</td>
   <td>NLRTM13029408</td> 
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <table>
  <html>
```

I has to be done in java.
If somebody can show some way to achieve this goal or give some tips it will be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Code writing services are not free. If you want help on this forum you would need to post valid code and ask a valid question.

Comment: Oke, thank you for that, I have tried something, i will post it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java XML library such as Apache [AXIOM](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/index.html) to manipulate XML. It is worth nothing, however, that the document you posted is not valid XML since some of the tags are not closed properly.

There are various ways to have AXIOM build the DOM depending on the source of your XML data.

See the AXIOM [Quick Start document](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/quickstart-samples.html) for more information. The following snippet, which constructs the DOM from a file, is from the aforementioned Quick Start document:

```
public void processFile(File file) throws IOException, OMException {
    // Create a builder for the file and get the root element
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    OMElement root = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(in).getDocumentElement();

    // Dome some processing...

    // Because Axiom uses deferred parsing, the stream must be closed AFTER
    // processing the document (unless OMElement#build() is called)
    in.close();
}
```

Once you have the DOM you can use facilities such as XPath to find the XML nodes you wish to manipulate (the attributes in your case), and remove them from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
XmlString=XmlString.replaceAll("\\<\\html(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
```